# Python : append multiple arguments to the tuple

Tags: python

I'd like to append multiple arguments to the tuple, but I don't know how

Here's my `dict()`:

```
OBJECTS = { item1 : 'None', item2 : 'None' }
```

**CODE:**

```
def a(file):
    fp = open(file, 'Ur')
    data_list = []
    for line in fp:
        data_list.append(tuple(line.strip().split('|')),OBJECTS)
    fp.close()
    return data_list
```

And Python return Error:

> TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: Of course you are appending two values : tuple and OBJECTS.

Comment: Perhaps `extend` is what you want.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. How does `OBJECTS` relate to the data you're reading from the file?

Comment: @Mr.Dave yes, get it, thank you

Comment: @user3100115 I'm doing it wrong, now I understand it. Can you delete my question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you can only append one item to the list at a time.

So, you want to call `append` twice:

```
data_list.append(tuple(line.strip().split('|')))
data_list.append(OBJECTS)
```

However, I'm not sure if you want to actually append `OBJECTS` to the array for each line, considering that `OBJECTS` is not dependent on the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate collections:

```
[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]

(1, 2, 3) + (4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: He is doing it all wrong. Perhaps he should point of the actual flaws in his code.